# WPF Getting CheckBox Content

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I am using Data Templates to set the values of checkboxes within a combobox as such:

```
<ComboBox Margin="118,117,163,164" ItemsSource="{Binding collection}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

This works as it should.  My problem is, when the user checks the box, I need to be able to get the content value stored within the checkbox.  Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "get the content value stored within the checkbox"?

Comment: I am assuming you mean you need all the Names which the user has checked/selected.

Comment: The text value for a Checkbox is stored as the Content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the Checkbox's **IsChecked** property to another property on the backing object for each item. i.e. the type which has the Name should expose a boolean property IsSelected.

Databinding will update the IsSelected property appropriately, which would be easy for you to access in code. e.g. you can loop over the list and filter all the items that have IsSelected = false.

Code Sample

XAML

```
<StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button Click="EvaluateSelectedItems">Show Selected</Button>
        <TextBlock>Selected Items</TextBlock>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Background="AliceBlue"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Code-behind

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;

    Items = new List<ItemVM>
                {
                    new ItemVM {IsSelected = false, Name = "Firefox"},
                    new ItemVM {IsSelected = false, Name = "Chrome"},
                    new ItemVM {IsSelected = false, Name = "IE"}
                };
}

public IEnumerable<ItemVM> Items { get; set; }
private IEnumerable<ItemVM> _selectedItems;
public IEnumerable<ItemVM> SelectedItems
{
    get { return _selectedItems; }
    set
    {
        _selectedItems = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedItems"));
    }
}

private void EvaluateSelectedItems(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SelectedItems = Items.Where(item => item.IsSelected);
}
```

Comment: Won't allow me to use binding on the Checked Property as it says it requires an event

Comment: The property name is IsChecked, the event when it is selected is Checked.

Comment: @Darren - yeah just glossed over that one.. The property you want to bind is IsChecked the boolean property on a checkbox. Updated..

Comment: How can I then use this to get the Content text from the checkbox?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Gishu, thanks very much. This works great.  Is there a way to have evaluate the selected objects without having to use a button?  The only event exposed by ObservableCollection isn't right for it.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Darren Since you can detect when any item's IsSelected property changes, each ItemVM can raise a PropertyChanged("IsSelected") event. You'd need to design a custom container/collection type (instead of an ObservableCollection) that listens to an event from any of its items. In the event handler for that, you could do whatever it is you wish to do when any item is checked - e.g. refresh selected items property.